# Embed not loading picture from URL [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to use a cragslist picture url as my thumbnail for my embed. However, it doesn't seem to load in. How do I fix this?

```
#Discord Modules
import discord
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
from discord.ext import commands

#Discord Variables
token = "..."
channelID = ...
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

  cragslistChannel = bot.get_channel(channelID) #text channel

  link = "..."
  imageURL = "http://images.craigslist.org/00t0t_5kQLEkwjBAnz_0fu0bC_600x450.jpg" #Image URL

  embed=discord.Embed(color=0xd84dfe) #embed
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=imageURL)
  embed.add_field(name="Link",value="||{}||".format(link), inline=False)

  await cragslistChannel.send(embed=embed) #Send to channel

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this alternative if thumbnails arent working:

```
embed.set_image(url="http://images.craigslist.org/00t0t_5kQLEkwjBAnz_0fu0bC_600x450.jpg")
```

Comment: The image and the thumbnail are two different things, so the image might not be a viable alternative for the thumbnail depending on the use case. I also somewhat doubt that the image would load as the image field but not as the thumbnail field.

Comment: I think only the position changes, the point is the same. That's why it's not a problem..

Comment: This method does not work.